# Façons de dire « it's a lot of fun »

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, expressions-idiomatiques

Je cherche des façons de dire des choses comme: « we had a blast », « it's a lot of fun », etc.

Serait-il correct de dire quelque chose comme: « jouer au volleyball, c'est très amusant ! » ?

Comment: oui, c'est correct. Mais, sauf si vous parlez à des personnes âgées,  vous pouvez dire : c'es trop cool, c'est super fun etc.

Answer (score 1):

Il y a de nombreuses expressions pour exprimer le fait qu'on a eu du plaisir ou qu'on s'est amusé:

Expressions courantes:

> C'était très amusant, on a passé un bon moment, on s'est bien amusés (assez neutre)

Expressions familières:

> C'était sympa, c'était chouette, on s'est bien marrés

Expressions encore plus familières:

> c'était le pied, on a pris notre pied (insiste sur le plaisir), on s'est éclatés (plus intense), on s'est fendu la poire (insiste sur le fait qu'on a beaucoup ri)

Expressions plus "jeunes", rares dans la bouche d'un "vieux" de plus de 30 ans:

> c'était cool, on a kiffé, on a surkiffé, c'était le kif, c'était trop bon, c'était trop cool

Comment: "**un "vieux" de plus de 30 ans**"   .. kiffer  n'est pas dans   Le Festin nu (1959) de  William Burroughs ?

Comment: "Kif" est à l'origine un mot arabe désignant un type de drogue issue du cannabis, et par extension une extase provenant de ses effets. Burroughs (ou son traducteur) y fait référence  dans ce sens. Mais le verbe "kiffer"  et le sens de "plaisir" sont plus récents (cf http://www.lefigaro.fr/langue-francaise/expressions-francaises/2017/11/16/37003-20171116ARTFIG00008-mais-d-o-vient-le-mot-kif.php).

Comment: plus récent peut-être (quoiqu'il me semble que dans le Festin Nu ce soit ce sens qui est utilisé, mais il y a des tas de gens de plus de 30 ans qui l'utilisent, il me semble .. non ? Mais peut-être alors que ce ne sont pas des vieux de plus de 30 ans, mais de jeunes de plus de 30 ans ?